# Fluent NHibernate Mapping: one-to-one (or none)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-one, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a following database scheme setup which I can't really change.

```
User
----
Id    (primary key)
[Some simple properties...]


UserAdditionalData
------------------
Id     (primary key)
[Some simple properties...] 
USERID (foreign key to User)
```

It's clear that the `User` table doesn't really have any recollection whether or not it is linked to a `UserAdditionalData` record, so I don't think I can call this a true one-to-one mapping here since they also don't share a mutually exclusive PK.

However, in practice, I would like to be able to work on a `User` object and for example check if it has a `UserAdditionalData` record and if so, access its properties.

I've set up my BDO as such:

```
public class User
{
    [Some simple properties...] 
    public virtual UserAdditionalData UserAdditionalData { get; set; }
}

public class UserAdditionalData
{
    [Some simple properties...] 
    public virtual User User { get; set; }  /* I have this here, 
                                               but I don't really ever 
                                               have to access it in this 
                                               direction */
}
```

I've set up my mapping as such:

```
    public UserMapping()
    {
        Table("USER");
        [Some simple properties...] 
        HasOne(x => x.UserAdditionalData).Cascade.None();
    }


    public UserExtraMapping()
    {
        Table("USER_ADDITIONAL_DATA");
        [Some simple properties...] 
        References(x => x.User, "USERID").Unique();
    }
```

This all compiles, but I see that my UserExtra object (when accessed via a User object) is always null.
I've tried a lot of different ways to go about it, read a lot on implementing this as a one-to-many. However, I'm still not being able to get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**[Small UPDATE]:** I only have to query the database, not save to it if that's relevant in any way.

Comment: The `HasOne` and `References` setup you have works for me. Does the SQL NHibernate is generating look correct to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your ***small update***, I would go with a simplified mapping. We would profit from NHibernate real mapping power, and also optimize the User loading. All that because we do need **Read-Only** mapping.

Firstly, we should introduce simple `int` property `UserId` on the *Additional* class

```
// extra class is having an int property containig the foreign key
public class UserAdditionalData
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
}

// that would be the mapping:
public UserExtraMapping()
{
    ...
    Map(x => x.UserId, "USERID");
}
```

Now, we will use well optimized mapping for lazy loading `many-to-one` *(I.e. in comparison with one-to-one which loads both ends always, here we will get the reference data only if really needed!)*

```
public UserMapping()
{
    ...
    References(x => x.UserAdditionalData)
          .LazyLoad()
          .PropertyRef(e => e.UserId)
          .Not.Insert()
          .Not.Update()
          ;
}
```

So, for readonly I would do the best to use `many-to-one` mapping (`References()`)

see also:

- [5.1.10. many-to-one](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)
- [mapping by code, ManyToOne](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html) *(scroll down to **Fluent NHibernate's equivalent**)*